# how should i change an instruction to NOP in IDA?

Tags: ida, assembly, arm, ios

I am new with IDA assembler and i used to work with hopper app.
the problem is i can't change instruction in IDA from something like CBNZ to NOP.
is there any button to do this? i can't find anything on the internet and I have been searching for it all day.
I have tried many options from the edit menu.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/how-could-i-change-an-instruction-in-ida-pro) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE:** I'm assuming you're using IDA 7.X, although this should work equally well for 6.X versions.

The option you're looking for is called `Patch Program`. For your specific question, you'd do the following:

1. Select the instruction you want to change
2. Go to `Edit -> Patch Program -> Assemble`
3. Replace the instruction in the text box with the instruction you'd like it to be.
4. Click OK

The original instruction will now have been replaced with the new one.

[This article](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ida-program-patching/) has more info and examples of using the other options in the `Patch Program` submenu.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried that before. the program says: sorry, this processor module doesn't support the assembler, I am trying to patch an ios arm7 app.

Comment: Are you using the free version? If you are, this might be a side effect of that. It's also possible that the error message is accurate and that feature really isn't available for iOS binaries; I'm not sure. Regardless, here are two examples of people using alternative methods to patch iOS binaries; maybe one of them will help. https://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=2172  https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-26-patching-ios-applications-using-ida-pro-hex-fiend